# Best way to convert hash keys to array only if their values are set to true

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to find an elegant and compact way to convert hash keys into array that contains only those that have true as value

```
example = {"foo" => true, "bar" => false, "baz" => true}
```

become

```
example = ["foo", "baz"]
```

Comment: _"I'm trying to find an elegant and compact way to convert hash keys into array that contains only those that have *true* as value"_. I don't think any of the answers (so far) have met your specification. In part it may be due to your example.

Comment: You wish to convert the value of `example` from a hash to an array. Imo, that is not good practice. I would suggest something like `true_keys` for the variable holding the keys having the value `true`.

Answer (score 4):

```
example = example.keys.select {|key| example[key].eql? true}

p example
```

output

```
["foo", "baz"]
```

Comment: Can be shortened to `example.keys.select { |key| example[key] }`

Comment: Actually I think your original answer was correct (apologies) because the OP is not interested if a value is a truthy, but whether it is the `true` object.

Comment: @Sagar Pandya Yes I can see that, reverted back.

Comment: @Cary Swoveland in his question it's clear that he wanted to change the same example variable into array.

Comment: Rajagopalan, I moved my comment to the question, where I intended it to be initially. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 4):

The shortest would be `example.select{|k, v| v}`

to extract the keys simply add `.keys`

EDIT: if like Cary suggests there would be other than boolean values you would have to check for `v == true` or `v.eql? true`

Comment: ahhh! Amazing way!

Comment: This returns a hash, OP requires an array of the keys.

Comment: you'r right, was a bit too quick, adapted the answer, Thnx

Comment: What about `{ 'a'=>1 }`?

Comment: srr Cary, I don't get it

Comment: The question is how to extract keys whose value is (the object) `true`, not whose values are truthy. (btw, I just happened to see your comment as I was not notified that you had left one. Please don't forget to start with @Cary.)

Comment: @Cary now I get it :) then you would check for v == true or .eql? true , all depends on what values can be present in your source, if only booleans I prefer the shorter version, on the other hand the longer version is more readable for non Ruby devs

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents:

```
example.collect{|k, v| k if v}.compact
```

output: `["foo", "baz"]`

Which can work also picking false:

```
example.collect{|k, v| k if !v}.compact
```

output: `["bar"]`

..or

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different ways to do this. Here's another one:

```
example.reduce([]) { |memo, (k, v)| v ? memo << k : memo }
```

Or, similarly:

```
example.each_with_object([]) { |(k, v), memo| memo << k if v }
```

Or you can use my nutty [piecewise](https://rubygems.org/gems/piecewise) gem:

```
example.piecewise { |yielder, (k, v)| yielder << k if v }
```